# GitKraken: ignore single file

Tags: gitkraken

I've a .gitgnore that contains

```
.gradle/
.idea/
build/
*.iml
local.properties
```

If I type 'git status' in command line, all is ok, but in GitKraken (v1.9.1 / Windows 10) it still displays the local.properties file in the change list (other rules are honored).

A bug? Bad configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Just noticed that there was a space at the end of the line.
I let this post, hoping that a GitKraken developer will see that and hopefully fix it ;)

Answer (score -1):

Gitkraken is very young and therefore still unreliable. You should destroy your directory of Git, do a new "git clone" and then use Gitkraken again. This will help for a few weeks. If you find anything not working, please clone again and again...

better to stop with Gitkraken, it may destroy your git archive when combining with command line!!